# How to "reverse" cat -A?

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing

Consider the following:

```
$ cat -A input.txt
Hello^IWorld$
newline$
```

Here, `cat -A` takes actual newlines and tabs, i.e. the real characters, and converts them to representations.

Is there a shell way or command-line application in Ubuntu repositories that would allow taking representations of unprintable characters and output the *real* values ?

In a sense, I'm asking whether there's something analogous to `$'Hello\tWorld\nnewline\n'`, except instead of C-quoted strings, I want use "shell-quoted" strings.

Comment: Does *od -c input.txt* head in the right direction?

Comment: @stumblebee  Nope. `od -c input.txt` produces C-quoted characters from file, which isn't what I was asking. I think I need to clarify the question. Basically  something like `cat -A input.txt |  some_command` should be able to give original contents of `input.txt`. You know how  when you do `echo  Hello$'\t'World`  and it gives actual  `Hello` then actual tab, then `World` ? Well, I'm looking for a way to convert 'Hello^IWorld' into  "Hello", then actual tab, then "World"

Comment: Isn't `tr` doing such things? `cat -A input.txt | tr $ \\n | tr ^I \\t` gives me a good result (with doubled newlines because `cat -A` doesn't replace, but just *mark* them), but considering you know way more than me I don't think that's what you actually are after. Why not `tr`?

Comment: @dessert like *cat -v input.txt*

Comment: @dessert  There's two problems: 1) `tr` requires  specifying multiple replacements, and in your example there's multiple pipes, so not a single command, requires accounting for all cases. 2) `tr` is single-character converter, with syntax `tr SET1 SET2`,  and if `SET1` has more characters than `SET2`  the replacement will be same for extra characters in SET1 as the last in SET2. For example, `echo "I am"$'\t'"tab" | tr '^I' $'\t'` will output `<tab>am<tab>tab`, i.e. `^I` isn't treated as control character but two literal characters, and replaced with single tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Python to the rescue!

Check out this one-liner, which reads from STDIN and prints to STDOUT, handling all possible "caret escapes"/"C0 codes" (like `^I`) and line-end indicators (`$`):

```bsh
python3 -c 'import sys,re;print(re.sub(r"\^([A-Z?@[\\\]^_])",lambda m:chr((ord(m.group(1))-64)&127),sys.stdin.read().replace("$\n","\n")))'
```

Actually it's both compatible with `python` (2) and `python3`. Here's a longer, more readable version doing basically the same:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, re

# read everything from stdin and remove line-end indicators
s = sys.stdin.read().replace("$\n", "\n"))

# replace caret escapes like ^I or ^M and output to stdout
print(re.sub(r"\^([A-Z?@[\\\]^_])", lambda m: chr((ord(m.group(1)) - 64) & 127), s)
```

So, first we remove the line-end indicators `$`.

Second we use the regular expression pattern `\^([A-Z?@[\\\]^_])` to find all valid characters following carets and replace both with the correct unescaped character, according to Wikipedia on [Caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) and [C0 control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes). Note how only capital letters `A`-`Z` or one of `?@[\]^_` have a special meaning.

Now to unescape such a C0 code, we take the position in the alphabet of the character succeeding the caret (found in `m.group(1)`), e.g. "A" is 1, "B" is 2 and so on. This is equal to its ASCII value minus the ASCII code of "A" plus one, which makes up the -64, which also explains e.g. "@" (ASCII 64) being 0 or "[" (ASCII 91) being ESC (ASCII 27). We do a binary AND operation on this number with 127 to only consider the first 7 bits of information, so that e.g. "?" (ASCII 63 == 64-1) wraps around to 127, representing the DEL character.

Finally after all these <del>highly complex</del> computations are done, we simply print the resulting string to STDOUT again.

Comment: Impressive Python-fu and insight into caret notation and control codes.  Learned something new.  While I hoped for a single command, a python script will do and I think it's even better to my taste.  Already upvoted, now accepted

Comment: Yeah, I learned that stuff today by looking up Wikipedia as well, always wondered where these escapes came from :D